# How to define nested class constants?

Tags: java, python, constants

I have these constants defined in `constants.py`

```
PERMISSION_USER_ADD = 'add_user'
PERMISSION_USER_VIEW = 'view_user'
PERMISSION_USER_EDIT = 'edit_user'
PERMISSION_TOOL_ADD = 'add_tool'
PERMISSION_TOOL_VIEW = 'view_tool'
PERMISSION_TOOL_EDIT = 'edit_tool'
```

But I do not want to have to type these full constant names out every time I need to add another one.

Coming from Java I could do this.

```
class Permission {
    class User {
        const ADD = 'add_user';
        const VIEW = 'view_user';
        const EDIT = 'edit_user';
    }
    class Tool {
        const ADD = 'add_tool';
        const VIEW = 'view_tool';
        const EDIT = 'edit_tool';
    }
}
```

But all python linters flag this as bad coding practice and searching for the python way to do it hasn't been fruitful so far.

So my question is: What's the pythonic way to define nested constants, in a way that supports easy refactoring?

Comment: A simple dictionary won't cut it?

Comment: Wouldn't you still have to do `Permission.User.ADD`? I don't see how you're saving any time.  If you're that worried about it, either give the constants shorter names or configure your editor to autocomplete.

Comment: @palivek a dictionary would work but then I would have to use `['user']['add']` to access the values. Not sure if that's the best way

Comment: @PatrickHaugh if I was adding a new permission, I would have to duplicate edit/type it out, whereas with nesting I could just add it in one place. I also lose the ability to nicely iterate over permissions. Then again this could just be my bias showing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`argparse.Namespace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#the-namespace-object) which let's you access the members just as for your class example:

```
>>> permissions = Namespace(
...     user=Namespace(add='add_user', etc),
...     etc
... )
```

And then:

```
>>> permissions.user.add
'add_user'
```

Comment: I've always wondered how others feel about using `argparse.Namespace` like this. I guess it borders on API abuse but it fits the OP's use case just perfectly.

Comment: @PriiduNeemre Actually, you could also use [`types.SimpleNamespace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html#types.SimpleNamespace) instead which seems more appropriate for the given use case.

Answer (score 0):

A dictionary is probably the easiest way to go.

```
class Permission(object):
    user = {
        'add': 'add_user',
        'view': 'view_user',
        'edit': 'edit_user',
    }
    tool = {
        'add' : 'add_tool',
        'view' : 'view_tool',
        'edit' : 'edit_tool',
    }

print(Permission.user['view'])
print(Permission.tool['view'])
```

output:

```
view_user
view_tool
```